# Adding a service to a new group on Kong ACL plugin

Tags: acl, api-key, kong

Is there a way on Access Control List plugin to assign a service endpoint behind Kong that already has some allowed-groups to a NEW group? To be more precise, I set up the ACL plugin of Kong with Key-Auth plugin and it works fine. But I could not find a way to create a new group (say "newgroup") and assign a service endpoint(say "myservice") to it that is already assigned to some of the groups(say "group1" and "group2"). So "myservice" has allowed-groups "group1" & "group2" and I also want to add it to "newgroup". Is there a way for that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This was not trivial, I don't have any supported documentation but... "It worked for me"

You have to find the current id for the plugin in the route and after that you can edit it

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://{KONG_API}/routes/{your_route}/plugins/{your_plugin_uuid}' \
    --data 'name=acl' \
    --data 'config.allow=group1' \
    --data 'config.allow=group2' \
    --data 'config.hide_groups_header=true'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).